# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mvvm

i have a bunch of view which are associated to the viewmodels and getting hte similar error for all the views and viewmodels. here is the code:

I have the following code:

```
    public static IReportViewModel GetViewModel(Type view)
    {
        try
        {
            return s_Locator.GetInstance(view, view.FullName) as IReportViewModel; <!-- I get the exception here-->
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }             
    }
```

The complete exception is here:

> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type AnnotetedReportViewModel, key "InsurableRisk.Reporting.ViewModels.Application.AnnotetedReportViewModel"

Can anyone explain or suggest what could have caused the exception?

Regards,
Sagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the spelling correct? I noticed that Annotated is spelled AnnotetedReportViewModel.  Also, is the assembly loaded into the project or does it exist in the bin folder?

Comment: The spelling is correct. I have made the spelling mistake in the begining, so i did not correct it. It does exist in the bin folder.

Comment: Debug by walking through this to see if the assembly is loaded.

    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(assembly.GetName().Name);

Comment: You can also force assembly references in your .config file.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx